# Error using Jquery Datepicker only on IE some pages

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Datepicker in my application.

It is working fine on all the browsers i.e Mozilla, Safari, Chrome etc. However when I am looking in IE 6.0 it giving below error.

**"Length is null or not a object".**

It is behaving specific for some page in IE 6. In some pages is working fine but in some page after selecting the date,the datepicker window does not get closed and display above error message.

I am using below jquery function for showing my datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {        
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: '../images1/calendar.gif', 
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',      
        showOtherMonths: true,
        showStatus: true
        });

    });
```

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling your datepicker with the following:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ onSelect:function(){}});
```

Fine, I'll do one 'send me teh codez':

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {        
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: '../images1/calendar.gif', 
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',      
        showOtherMonths: true,
        showStatus: true,
        onSelect:function(){}
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, PLease see my datepicker function above, please suggest what should i do to fix it. please use my above function! and tell me what needs to be changed